# Rocket towing an object

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

I'm not sure if my question makes sense, but I don't know where to start.

A crate of mass $m_2$ is connected by a massless rope of constant length $l$ to a rocket of mass $m_1$. We take into account gravity (the crate is initially hanging directly underneath), but the rocket has no vertical acceleration since it's acted upon by an upward force of $(m_1+m_2)*g$. We neglect air drag and treat the rocket and the crate it is towing as blocks of the same size. If a horizontal force $F$ acts upon the rocket, what happens to the crate? It's probably going to lag behind at a certain angle, but how can we find that angle? Is the situation different if there's no gravity?

Edit: This link helped me answer my question: http://cnx.org/content/m14061/latest/?collection=col10322/1.83

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a problem like this the first thing to do is draw a diagram. Mark in all the angles and all the forces you think are acting. I think the diagram looks like this:

[image: Rocket towing mass]

Your question is what angle, $\theta$, does the rope make to the vertical. Since this is a homework problem I'm not going to answer it directly, but note that the horizontal acceleration of the mass, $m_2$, must be equal to the acceleration of the rocket otherwise the mass would be accelerating relative to the rocket. A bit of basic trigonometry and you should have your angle.

Comment: The acceleration of both should be same and not forces. Same forces -> different accelerations.

Comment: @JohnRennie, what did you use to create that picture, thanks

Comment: @Derg: [Google Draw](https://support.google.com/docs/topic/1360903?hl=en&ref_topic=1397170). It's a fairly basic drawing app but it's free and available everywhere. I do the drawing then [screen shot](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows-xp/help/setup/take-a-screen-shot) it and save it as a GIF.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no air-drag/air-friction following two cases will be observed

Take note, you can get wrong answers while working with forces, try to work with accelerations here.

`In presence of gravity`

[image]

Here you can easily find $\theta$ using basic trigonometry

> $\tan\theta = \frac{g}{a}$

`In absence of gravity`

[image]

Clearly the angle here is $0^\text{o}$

Comment: How do we justify the assumption that the horizontal distance between the two objects is equal to $a$ (in the presence of gravity)?

Comment: That's the acceleration. Please see again "a" is written in front of a ray and not on a line segment.

Comment: Yes, but if we're going to use trigonometry, we'll have to have to treat $a$ as a length, won't we?

Comment: Have you never used velocties (vertical and horizontal) in a parabola to find angle of trajectory?  No! We do not have to treat it as length.